# Addition in Java program equals different value

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with this Java code. It's a questionnaire that should calculate your grade. It all goes and runs well until the very last part where it says "current score" that whole equation should equal 33.16 but instead it equals 24.

I changed some values, did some research but I haven't found what I'm looking for.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Grading Scale:");
        System.out.println("A\t 90 - 100");
        System.out.println("B\t 80 - 89");
        System.out.println("C\t 70 - 79");
        System.out.println("D\t 60 - 69");
        System.out.println("F\t below 60");

        System.out.println("What letter grade do you want to achieve for the course?");
        String desiredGrade;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        desiredGrade = keyboard.next();

        if (desiredGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("A") || desiredGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("B")
                || desiredGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("C") || desiredGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("D")
                || desiredGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {// is this necessary? vv
            System.out.println("Enter Percentage Weights");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Input error.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int exam1, exam2, finalExam, labs, projects, attendance, quizzes;

        System.out.println("Exam 1:\t");
        exam1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Exam 2:\t");
        exam2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Final Exam:\t");
        finalExam = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Labs:\t");
        labs = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Projects:\t");
        projects = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Attendance:\t");
        attendance = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Quizzes:\t");
        quizzes = keyboard.nextInt();

        // so the semicolon isn't needed after the if statement?
        if (exam1 + exam2 + finalExam + labs + projects + attendance + quizzes != 100) {
            System.out.println("Weights don't add up to 100, program exiting");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Enter your scores out of a 100:");
        System.out.println("Do you know your Exam 1 score?");

        String answer;
        int exam1score = 0, exam2score = 0, finalExamScore = 0, labAverage = 0, projectAverage = 0, quizAverage = 0, attendanceAverage = 0;
        double currentScore = 0;
        answer = keyboard.next();

        // ask about this

        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            // why can't i put int here?
            System.out.println("Score received on exam 1:");
            exam1score = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Do you know your Exam 2 score?");
            answer = keyboard.next();

            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                System.out.println("Score received on exam 2:");
                exam2score = keyboard.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Do you know your Final Exam score?");
                answer = keyboard.next();
           }
           if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                System.out.println("Score received on final exam");
                finalExamScore = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Do you know your lab average?");
        answer = keyboard.next();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                System.out.println("Average Lab Grade:");
                labAverage = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Do you know your project average?");
        answer = keyboard.next();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("Average Project Grade:");
            projectAverage = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Do you know your quiz average?");
        answer = keyboard.next();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("Average Quiz Grade:");
            quizAverage = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Do you know your attendance average?");
        answer = keyboard.next();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("Average Attendance Grade:");
            attendanceAverage = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        currentScore = ((double)exam1score*exam1 + exam2score*exam2 +finalExam*finalExamScore + labs*labAverage + projects*projectAverage + attendance*attendanceAverage + quizzes*quizAverage)/((double)exam1+exam2+finalExam+labs+projects+attendance+quizzes);
        System.out.println("Current Grade Score:\t " + currentScore);

        String grade;

        if (currentScore >= 90)
            grade = "A";
        else if (currentScore >= 80)
            grade = "B";
        else if (currentScore >= 70)
            grade = "C";
        else if (currentScore >= 60)
            grade = "D";
        else
            grade = "F";
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your inputs when you run it?

Comment: without knowing your inputs, how can we say why you are not getting 33.16 as the final value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following only converts the `exam1score*exam1` value to `double`, not the entire expression.

```
(double) exam1score*exam1 + exam2score*exam2 + finalExam*finalExamScore + ....
```

So, you should do something like this.

```
int nominator = exam1score*exam1 + exam2score*exam2 + finalExam*finalExamScore 
                        + labs*labAverage + projects*projectAverage 
                        + attendance*attendanceAverage + quizzes*quizAverage;
int denominator = exam1 + exam2 + finalExam + labs + projects + attendance + quizzes;
currentScore = (double) nominator / denominator;
```

OR

```
int nominator = exam1score*exam1 + exam2score*exam2 + finalExam*finalExamScore
                        + labs*labAverage + projects*projectAverage 
                        + attendance*attendanceAverage + quizzes*quizAverage);
int denominator = exam1 + exam2 + finalExam + labs + projects + attendance + quizzes;
currentScore = (nominator * 1.0) / denominator;
```

Comment: Thank you @Wasi ! it worked like a charm! I really appreciate it :D

Answer (score 0):

```
(double)exam1score*exam1 + exam2score*exam2 +finalExam*finalExamScore + labs*labAverage + projects*projectAverage + attendance*attendanceAverage + quizzes*quizAverage
```

only converts the first one to `double` and leaves the rest as `int`.

Comment: Hello @John thank you for your quick assistance :D

I tried it but it equals 24.2 :( I'd really appreciate if you could help me. This project has me frustrated